# Dropping rows from a df rises a SettingWithCopyWarning error (Pandas, Python) when value doesn't exist (using inplace=T)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am trying to drop some rows based on a specific value of a dataframe:

```
dd = {'ae': pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,4], b=[4,5,6])),
      'be': pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[13,21,413], b=[456,54,62]))}
def test_remove(dd, val):
      test = dd.get('ae')
      test.drop(test.loc[test['a']==val].index, inplace=True)
test_remove(dd, 24242)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4906:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame

Please advise what is wrong here? I have a dictionary of dataframes, I am trying to get into each of them and remove a row based on a specific column value.

Comment: Great explanation to avoid using inplace=True: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-probably-never-use-pandas-inplace-true-9f9f211849e4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing the remove in place, it would be better to do something like this:

```
dd = {'ae': pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,4], b=[4,5,6])),
      'be': pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[13,21,413], b=[456,54,62]))}
def remove_rows(dd, key, val, col):
    dd[key] = dd[key].drop(dd[key].loc[dd[key][col]==val].index)
    return dd
dd = remove_rows(dd, 'ae', 413, 'a')
```

Comment: But what is the reason for the warning I get? @od1995

Comment: @SteveS you're dropping rows on the variable `test`, which is just a copy of `dd['ae']`. If you try to drop rows using your current function `test_remove`, nothing actually happens to the dataframes in `dd`. Print `dd` before and after calling `test_remove` to see this

Comment: Why inplace = True generate this warning? It works, and deletes the row but why do I get the warning? @od1995

Comment: I did what you've suggested and it's not the situation. It do remove the desired row. @od1995